# Reshaping data in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I have a simple table like

```
time_stamp, metric, value
2012/3/2  , x     , 1
2012/3/2  , y     , 1.6
2012/3/3  , x     , 0
2012/3/3  , y     , null
...
```

and I want to write a query that returns something like

```
time_stamp, x, y
2012/3/2  , 1, 1.6
2012/3/3  , 0, null
```

In other words, basically generate columns based on unique values of one field on the fly and reshape data into it.

I remember I have seen it somewhere, but I just cannot find it now.

PS. I am using PostgreSQL as of now. Please note if the solution is specific to a particular DBMS.

Updates: The values of the metric, from which columns are being formed are dynamic. I understand that makes this harder though and a single query solution almost impossible.

As per comments, I have tried crosstab as well and it is a) very pg specific and b) not so nice with dynamic number of tables.

Comment: It's called a PIVOT, and I don't know if Postgres has a built in function for it or not.

Comment: [PostgreSQL's tablefunc module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html) includes functions that return pivot tables.

Comment: What's the structure of the table? (CREATE TABLE statement) Is the combination of {time_stamp, metric} unique?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' It is more complicated than that, the short answer, no they are not unique (but can be made unique through a query)

Comment: If {time_stamp, metric} is not unique, how do you choose which value to include in the result set?

Comment: with another flag field, they will be unique

Answer (score 4):

Use `conditional aggregate` to transpose the rows.

```
select time_stamp,
      max(case when metric= 'X' then value End) as X, 
      max(case when metric= 'Y' then value End) as Y, 
From Yourtable
group by time_stamp
```